# proove that $\sum_{t=0}^{r}\binom{ m-t}{r-t} = \binom{ m + 1}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I tried to solve a question in combinatorics and ended up with this sum:

$\sum_{t=0}^{r}\binom{ m-t}{r-t}$

when I give it to WolframAlpha it says it equals to  $\binom{ m + 1}{r}$ but gives no proof, can someone provide a discrete proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{t=0}^r \binom{m-t}{r-t} = \sum_{t=0}^r \binom{m-t}{m - r}  = \sum_{t=m-r}^m \binom{t}{m - r} = \binom{m + 1}{m-r + 1} = \binom{m + 1}{r}$

the third $= $ is the Hockey-stick identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

How many $r$-element subsets are there of $\{0,1,2,\dots,m\}$?

---

How many of them don't contain $0$?

How many contain $0$ but not $1$?

How many contain $0$ and $1$ but not $2$?

...

How many contain the first $t$ many numbers but not the $t+1$'st?

Comment: any discrete way? perhaps using induction?

Comment: @OferMagen what is unsatisfactory about a combinatorial proof?  Most people *prefer* this method of proof as it gives more intuition as to what is going on.  This could easily be reworded with symbols if you absolutely insist, by writing $\binom{[n+1]}{r}=E_0\sqcup E_1\sqcup\dots \sqcup E_r$ where $E_t=\{\{0,1,2,\dots,t-1\}\cup A~:~A\in\binom{\{t+1,t+2,\dots,m\}}{r-t}\}$, but that just muddies things up in my opinion.

Comment: because when you have a combinatorial question and you use a completely different  combinatorial question the proof gets longer

Comment: plus induction is more "set in stone" than logic

Comment: what is a r-element subset

Comment: @OferMagen, the answer to your original question, to prove that $\sum\limits_{t=0}^r\binom{m-t}{r-t}=\binom{m+1}{r}$, can be answered with as few words as "The right hand side counts the number of $r$-element subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,m+1\}$ while the left hand side counts the same by breaking into cases based on the number of consecutive numbers starting at zero are in the subset."  This requires no fancy algebra, no fancy computations, and hardly any work at all beyond recognizing what each term in the sum represents and recognizing why they both represent the same total.

Comment: "*What is an $r$-element subset*"  it is a subset with $r$ elements...